# How to understand redis-cli's result vs redis-benchmark's result

Tags: redis

First, I am new to Redis.

So, I measure latency with `redis-cli`:

```
$ redis-cli --latency
min: 0, max: 31, avg: 0.55 (5216 samples)^C
```

OK, on average I get response in 0.55 milliseconds. From this I assume that **using only one connection** in 1 second I can get: 1000ms / 0.55ms = 1800 requests per second.

Then on the same computer I run `redis-benchmark` using **only one connection** and get more than 6000 requests per second:

```
$ redis-benchmark -q -n 100000 -c 1 -P 1
PING_INLINE: 5953.80 requests per second
PING_BULK: 6189.65 requests per second
```

So having measured latency I expected to get around 2000 request per seconds at best. However I got 6000 request per second. I cannot find explanation for it. Am I correct when I calculate: 1000ms / 0.55ms = 1800 requests per second?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, your maths are correct.

IMO, the discrepancy comes from scheduling artifacts (i.e. to the behavior of the operating system scheduler or the network loopback).

redis-cli latency is implemented by a loop which only sends a PING command before waiting for 10 ms. Let's try an experiment and compare the result of redis-cli --latency with the 10 ms wait state and without.

In order to be accurate, we first make sure the client and server are always scheduled on deterministic CPU cores. Note: it is generally a good idea to do it for benchmarking purpose on NUMA boxes. Also, make sure the frequency of the CPUs is blocked to a given value (i.e. no power mode management).

```
# Starting Redis
numactl -C 2 src/redis-server redis.conf
# Running benchmark
numactl -C 4 src/redis-benchmark -n 100000 -c 1 -q -P 1 -t PING
PING_INLINE: 26336.58 requests per second
PING_BULK: 27166.53 requests per second
```

Now let's look at the latency (with the 10 ms wait state):

```
numactl -C 4 src/redis-cli --latency
min: 0, max: 1, avg: 0.17761 (2376 samples)
```

It seems too high compared to the throughput result of redis-benchmark.

Then, we alter the source code of redis-cli.c to remove the wait state, and we recompile. The code has also been modified to display more accurate figures (but less frequently, because there is no wait state anymore).

```
Here is the diff against redis 3.0.5:
1123,1128c1123
<             avg = ((double) tot)/((double)count);
<         }
<         if ( count % 1024 == 0 ) {
<             printf("\x1b[0G\x1b[2Kmin: %lld, max: %lld, avg: %.5f (%lld samples)",
<                 min, max, avg, count);
<             fflush(stdout);
---
>             avg = (double) tot/count;
1129a1125,1127
>         printf("\x1b[0G\x1b[2Kmin: %lld, max: %lld, avg: %.2f (%lld samples)",
>             min, max, avg, count);
>         fflush(stdout);
1135a1134
>         usleep(LATENCY_SAMPLE_RATE * 1000);
```

Note that this patch should not be used against a real system, since it will make the redis-client --latency feature expensive and intrusive for the performance of the server. Its purpose is just to illustrate my point for the current discussion.

Here we go again:

```
numactl -C 4 src/redis-cli --latency
min: 0, max: 1, avg: 0.03605 (745280 samples)
```

Surprise! The average latency is now much lower. Furthermore, 1000/0.03605=27739.25, which is completely in line with the result of redis-benchmark.

Morality: the more the client loop is scheduled by the OS, the lower the average latency. It is wise to trust redis-benchmark over redis-cli --latency if your Redis clients are active enough. And anyway keep in mind the average latency does not mean much for the performance of a system (i.e. you should also look at the latency distribution, the high percentiles, etc. ..)

Comment: In recent Redis versions there is `redis-cli --latency-dist` that will show the latency distribution by making multiple requests. Using `--latency-dist` together with `-i` allows to specify the sampling interval.

Comment: This patch kinda fixes the problem but has other problems: https://gist.github.com/antirez/31d4fd73ef18834414e9. The idea is to sample during brusts and pause a lot more later. However this will hardly spot instantaneous latency spikes since requests are no longer evenly distributed so unlikely to be a good change.

Comment: Yes - it was not meant to be applied for a real system, just to illustrate the issue. I will add something to make it clear.

Comment: Yep... but it's a shame it shows wrong data. Maybe in latency mode it should warn about this, and at the same time the delay should be controllable via options, so that it's possible to also run a reliable test.